# How to render nested object elements map method

Tags: json, reactjs

here is the my json data, i want to use "name" in products.

```
list:[ { id: 1, suppliercard:{ iduser: 5, supplier:{ product:[{name: "ment"}] } } } ]
```

here is my code

```
 list.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <ul >{item.id}</ul>
            item.suppliercard.supplier.product.map((subitem, i) => {
              return (
                 <p>{subitem.name}</p>
              )
            })
          </div>
        )
      })
```

it's not working

Comment: this should work...

Comment: Please edit... missing things like: what is it not working? what is the error that you get? etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap `item.suppliercard.supplier.product.map` in `{ }` because it is not `jsx` but `javascript` that should be executed. Try this:

```
list.map((item, index) => {
      return (<div key={index}>
        <ul>{item.id}</ul>
        {
          item.suppliercard.supplier.product.map((subitem, i) => 
          (<p>{subitem.name}</p>)) 
        }
      </div>)
    })
```

Comment: @mahigorige25, could you mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem?